# How to test for asp.net login issue on remote web server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET webforms/MVC project that uses ASP.NET Identity.  User logins work fine on my local machine and have been working fine for the last year on the remote web server.  Recently users started experiencing login issues.  The login page would just take the user back to the home page without logging them in.  I cannot replicate the problem on my local machine.  What can I do to test/debug it on the remote web server?  I thought it might be a CDN caching or firewall issue, but I disabled both and the issue persists.

Comment: HAs anyting changed recently on the server? Is there any cross-domain iframing? Is it ALL the time or some of the time? Can you replicate the issue on the remote server? Is it browser dependent? Use dev tools in your browser to ensure the session cookie is set and not blocked. Add some server side logging so you have some idea where in the process  the problem is occuring.

Comment: Jon - thanks for the feedback.  There is no cross-domain iframing.  It happens intermittently.  I cannot replicate the problem on a remote server.  It happens on both Edge and Chrome.  Today, I was able to login through Chrome but not Edge.  If I recycle the IIS Application Pool it clears the problem.  I will do some testing on the cookie next.